# PHP Login check function responsible for increased page speed

Tags: php, authentication

I have a user authentication function in PHP that checks user information when logged inn. I have placed it in the header of every pages where a user is required to be logged in. After further investigation when moving my web page to a dedicated Windows Server this week, I noticed that page load is increased by this particular function. Talking about seconds.

My experience with PHP is not so good that I can re-write the function or think about a better solution. I can definitely see it's a heavy thing going on there; checking database, user agent, hash and etc every time a page loads. So my question is: is it possible to run this function only one time per session? In that case, how should it be structured? What would be a better solution?

```
function login_check($mysqli) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'], 
                        $_SESSION['username'], 
                        $_SESSION['login_string'])) {

        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $login_string = $_SESSION['login_string'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];

        $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password 
                                      FROM members 
                                      WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1")) {
            // Bind "$user_id" to parameter. 
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
            $stmt->execute();   // Execute the prepared query.
            $stmt->store_result();

            if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                $stmt->bind_result($password);
                $stmt->fetch();
                $login_check = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);

                if ($login_check == $login_string) {
                    // Logged In!!!! 
                    return true;
                } else {

                    return false;
                }
            } else {

                return false;
            }
        } else {

            return false;
        }
    } else {

        return false;
    }
}
```

You can see the whole script at
http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Comment: Why would you store their password in a session and then query the DB to check it each page load?  When they login just set a session var like `username` or `authenticated=true` or something and check that each page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only be querying the database once per session for that user. Instead, just create a simple script at the top of each page you need to protect that checks if they are signed in or not. For example:

```
<?php
session_start();
// If user_id is NOT SET then they are not signed in
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    // Send them somewhere else (login page maybe?) and exit
    header("Location: somepage.php");
    exit;
}
// If they made it here, they have a valid session
// TODO Code
```